# Как использовать mapstruct если одно из полей объекта это list<OtherObject> который тоже конвертируется

Tags: java, spring, rest, mapstruct

Есть 2 объекта, они идентичны. Но один определен в сторонней библиотеке, которая вызывается через rest моего проекта.

Т.е. мне нужно сохранить в моем объекте, объект полученный через rest.

Схема объекта и мапперов:

```
@Mapper
public interface ResponseConverter {
    ResponseConverter INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(ResponseConverter .class);
    @Mapping(source = "source.code", target = "code")
    @Mapping(source = "source.message", target = "message")
    @Mapping(source = "source.statuses", target = "statuses")
    ResponseConverter toRfModel(ru...fromREST...model.ResponseConverter source);
}

@Mapper
public interface StatusConverter {
    StatusConverter INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(StatusConverter.class);
    @Mapping(source = "source.paymentId", target = "paymentId")
    @Mapping(source = "source.statusCode", target = "statusCode")
    Status toRfModel(ru..fromREST...Status source);
}
```

Сам объект:

```
public class Response { 
    private String code; 
    private String message; 
    private List<Status> statuses; 
}
```

Как правильно настроить мапинг для полей `private List<Status> statuses`?

Сейчас при вызове `ResponseConverter.INSTANCE.toRfModel(response_from_rest);` падает ошибка  `Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError`

Comment: Это опечатка при подготовке кода для вопроса или у Вас в коде также в роли исходного и конечного класса выступает `ResponseConverter`?

Comment: Вы уверены, что у исходных классов есть поле `source`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо прописать отдельный метод конвертации коллекции:

```
List<Target> sourceListToTargetList(List<Source> sourceList);
```

Более подробно можно почитать в официальной документации - [Mapping collections](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#mapping-collections)